# Mirror second monitor?

Tags: windows-xp, vnc, tightvnc

Can I configure [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com) or any other VNC server for Windows XP to mirror the second monitor via VNC?

Answer (score 1):

I just found that after starting `tightvnc` as app, then I can move it to the second screen by running:

```
tvnserver -controlapp -sharedisplay 2
```

When running TightVNC as service, use `-controlservice` instead of `-controlapp`.